# ANOVA for high cardinal features

Tags: python, categories, correlation, anova

I have multiple high cardinal categorical features also low cardinal features. The target feature is numerical. I can know the correlation between low cardinal features and target variable with below code

```
F, p = stats.f_oneway(df[df.some_variable=='value_1'].Target,df[df.some_variable=='value_2'].Target)
print(F)
```

Here the above feature is low cardinal and has only two distinct values. How can I find the correlation if the feature has high cardinality , for example 400 distinct values. any suggestions and alternative ideas are appreciated. Thank you for your patience

Comment: If your question is about implementing the same concept but for multiple values it can be done with a simple loop, if it's about the correctness of using ANOVA on high cardinal features u should visit [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming `vals` is a list of values

```
df_arr = [df[df.some_variable==val].Target for val in vals]
F, p = stats.f_oneway(*df_arr)
```